# what exactly makes the car stealthy?

Tags: watch-dogs

I just recently got the papavero stealth edition car in watch dogs and it says when you click on it that its "A unique superior with STEALTH ABILITIES." My question is I guess what is it that makes it so superior and stealthy? The paint job, the tinted windows, what?

Comment: I might be wrong about this, which is why I'm not posting it as an answer, but from what I can tell the only 'stealthy' thing about it is the fact that it's painted black. Realistically, people would focus their attention on a swank black sports car like that, so unless there's some sort of not my problem field around it, it doesn't have anything. That said, for some reason, the cops do seem less likely to notice it?

Comment: @Snowskeeper I dont think that Watch Dogs simulates human vision. Rather the game knows in which radius you have to be to draw attention. Maybe this circle of suspicion is smaller in the "stealth car"

Comment: Watch Dogs wiki says, that it's useful in Online Hacking because you cannot be seen throu the tinted window

Comment: @JonasDralle Yep; that was what I was thinking. But I'm trying to assume that its actual 'superior stealth' qualities would somehow be tied to the features of the car, and those seemed to be what Tony was asking about.

Answer (score 2):

There's now a Wiki article detailing what makes it stealthy.

Player vs Player

**Pros:**

> A unique trait featured on the Stealth Edition that is not seen on any
>   other vehicle is **its extremely dark tinted windows**. This feature can
>   be very useful in Online Hacking and Online Tailing game-modes to
>   avoid being easily seen when driving or parked.

**Cons:**

> However, due to the
>   fact it is unobtainable without a Uplay account, and is not available
>   outside of the Car On Demand app, players aware of these facts may be
>   able to easily recognize the signature differences between it and the
>   base model, unless it is at very dark places or at night.

Player vs Computer

**Pros:**

> This edition, as the name indicates, is supposedly effective in
>   evading and eluding police, Club hitmen, Fixers and Viceroys. ... This can
>   be noted because its standard counterpart, the Papavero, seems to take
>   more time to lose the police. This may be because the windows are not
>   tinted, allowing the police to easily see Aiden.

**Cons:**

> It can be noted, however, CTOS scans take longer to complete when
>   driving the car.

Source: http://watchdogs.wikia.com/wiki/Papavero_Stealth_Edition